# A Faster Way of Removing Unused Categories in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I'm running some models in Python, with data subset on categories.

For memory usage, and preprocessing, all the categorical variables are stored as category data type.

For each level of a categorical variable in my 'group by' column, I am running a regression, where I need to reset all my categorical variables to those that are present in that subset.

I am currently doing this using `.cat.remove_unused_categories()`, which is taking nearly 50% of my total runtime. At the moment, the worst offender is my grouping column, others are not taking as much time (as I guess there are not as many levels to drop).

Here is a simplified example:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
#generate some fake data
alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
keywords = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(alphabets, repeat = 2)]
z = pd.DataFrame({'x':keywords})

#convert to category datatype
z.x = z.x.astype('category')

#groupby
z = z.groupby('x')

#loop over groups
for i in z.groups:
    x = z.get_group(i)
    x.x = x.x.cat.remove_unused_categories()
    #run my fancy model here
```

On my laptop, this takes about 20 seconds. for this small example, we could convert to str, then back to category for a speed up, but my real data has at least 300 lines per group.

Is it possible to speed up this loop? I have tried using `x.x = x.x.cat.set_categories(i)` which takes a similar time, and `x.x.cat.categories = i`, which asks for the same number of categories as I started with.

Comment: can you try this: `x = z.get_group(i).astype({'x':'str'}).astype({'x':'category'})` and remove this line: `x.x = x.x.cat.remove_unused_categories()`? it's interesting whether it'll be faster...

Comment: this speeds up the example, but my real data has 3-400 lines per by group, and a string conversion is slower in that case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is in that you are assigning `z.get_group(i)` to `x`.  `x` is now a copy of a portion of `z`.  Your code will work fine with this change

```
for i in z.groups:
    x = z.get_group(i).copy() # will no longer be tied to z
    x.x = x.x.cat.remove_unused_categories()
```

Comment: but it'll still copy all categories from the parent DF - do you think it'll be much faster?

Comment: I'm not sure what OP is doing!  So I have to trust them and `#run my fancy model here`.  I ran this code and it was painfully slow because it was outputting SetWithCopy warnings.  I change that line and it completed in no time.

Comment: Now I've run it, this is for sure the problem with my original code. Thanks a million - you can see the problem is still there if we increase `repeat =2` to 3 in the data construction, but this has decreased from .5 of runtime to 0.05.

Comment: SettingWithCopy warnings are not false positives; further they may do a garbage collection (which can be expensive) to find references