# drop unused categories using groupby on categorical variable in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

As per [Categorical Data - Operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#operations), by default `groupby` will show “unused” categories:

```
In [118]: cats = pd.Categorical(["a","b","b","b","c","c","c"], categories=["a","b","c","d"])

In [119]: df = pd.DataFrame({"cats":cats,"values":[1,2,2,2,3,4,5]})

In [120]: df.groupby("cats").mean()
Out[120]: 
      values
cats        
a        1.0
b        2.0
c        4.0
d        NaN
```

How to obtain the result with the “unused” categories dropped? e.g.

```
  values
cats        
a        1.0
b        2.0
c        4.0
```

Comment: If you search it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534489/a-faster-way-of-removing-unused-categories-in-pandas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Faster Way of Removing Unused Categories in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534489/a-faster-way-of-removing-unused-categories-in-pandas)

Comment: Hmm, the same function is used there, but I have no idea what it's doing. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since version 0.23 you can specify `observed=True` in the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) call to achieve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 12):

**Option 1**
[`remove_unused_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#removing-unused-categories)

```
df.groupby(df['cats'].cat.remove_unused_categories()).mean()

      values
cats        
a          1
b          2
c          4
```

You can also make the assignment first, and then `groupby` -

```
df.assign(cats=df['cats'].cat.remove_unused_categories()).groupby('cats').mean()
```

Or,

```
df['cats'] = df['cats'].cat.remove_unused_categories()
df.groupby('cats').mean()
```

```
      values
cats        
a          1
b          2
c          4
```

---

**Option 2**
[`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to `str` conversion -

```
df.groupby(df['cats'].astype(str)).mean()

      values
cats        
a          1
b          2
c          4
```

Comment: This answer is now outdated. See the more modern solution using `observed=True` argument to `groupby`.

Answer (score 3):

Just chain with [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html). Like so:

```
df.groupby("cats").mean().dropna()

      values
cats
a        1.0
b        2.0
c        4.0
```

Comment: I was rather looking for the`remove_unused_categories` solution, as the example is not my exact usecase and this solution does not help.

Comment: Should be obvious, but this will also remove categories that have an actual NaN value, not just categories that aren't present.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove unused categories from all categorical columns, you can:

```
def remove_unused_categories(df: pd.DataFrame):
    for c in df.columns:
        if pd.api.types.is_categorical_dtype(df[c]):
            df[c].cat.remove_unused_categories(inplace=True)
```

Then before calling `groupby`, call:

```
remove_unused_categories(df_with_empty_cat)
```