# Dropping Unused Categories in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a Dataframe which has a selection of rows which are within a range of dates.  They have a 'day' column which is the numeric day of the month between 1 and 31.  The 'day' column is dtype 'category'.

I want to graph these rows sorted by day in a FacetGrid (as shown below), but need to remove the extra empty graphs.

I was thinking of doing so by removing the unused 'day' categories before plotting by using groupby and remove_unused_categories(), however this isn't working (or my implementation is incorrect).  I'm currently using the implementation from this previous solution:

[drop unused categories using groupby on categorical variable in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48064965/drop-unused-categories-using-groupby-on-categorical-variable-in-pandas)

```
 dataframe.assign(day=dataframe.day.cat.remove_unused_categories())
 graph = sns.FacetGrid(timeframe, col="day")
```

How can I fix the implementation of remove_unused_categories() or use an alternate solution altogether.

This produces the following image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y8SL.jpg

*Unrelated but 'day' 01 is always out of order in-line.  The fix is probably quick but I don't really have the understanding of matplotlib/seaborn to fix it

Comment: Can you create a small example demonstrating this functionality? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples