# Seaborn not plotting head but instead plots whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I have a dataframe that I `groupby()` count and then `sort_values()` by count. I then take the `head()` and `tail()` of this dataframe to plot on a seaborn `barplot()`. However, when I try to plot the head it shows the whole original dataframe instead of only the `head()` products.

```py
most_popular_products= (items
 .groupby("product_name")
 .product_name.agg(["count"])
 .reset_index()
 .sort_values(by="count", ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
)
```

```py
top_5_products = most_popular_products.head()
bottom_5_products = most_popular_products.tail()
```

Then I plot:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))

sns.barplot(x=top_5_products["product_name"], y=top_5_products["count"])
```

[image]

How I can only plot the top 5?

Comment: Your `product_name` variable likely has a categorical dtype.

Comment: so how do I adjust for this?

Comment: @SeanO'Connor [how to drop unused categories after groupby on categorical variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48064965/13138364)

Comment: @tdy perfect this is exactly what I needed. When you use head() pandas seems to still keep track of how many categories there are. So I had to `top_5_products.product_name = top_5_products.product_name.cat.remove_unused_categories()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems when you use `head()` or take any slice of data the pandas column seems to still keep track of how many categories there are.

So if you take the top 5 but then list of the type of the column it will show that it still is made up of 20+ categories.

So I had to `top_5_products.product_name = top_5_products.product_name.cat.remove_unused_categories()`

This gives you only 5 categories for the column and then you can plot!